# Disk I/O operation CPU affinity

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

Can anyone help me find on which core a disk I/O operation will execute?

The file write application is running on core 11 .

Kernel threads affinity is configured to 0-1, IRQ affinity is set to 0-1, core from 2 to 11 are isolated from kernel scheduling. These are all configured in grub.

I/O scheduling policy is best effort and algorithm is CFQ.

I am using CentOS 7.4 with kernel 3.10.0-693

Comment: Core 11 will write the data to block cache. Background writes are done by the flush tasks.

Comment: where this flush tasks will run ?

Comment: Do you have the ps command on your system?